# Изменение стиля страницы кнопкой без перезагрузки

Tags: html, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток.

1 апреля на ютубе возле иконки автора видео видел замечательную кнопочку (выключатель), при нажатии на которую страница меняла стиль с одного на другой, при этом страница не перезагружалась, даже видео.

Подскажите, как такое можно реализовать? (Имеем style/style1.css и style/style2.css).

Comment: [Вот так](http://otvety.google.ru/otvety/thread?tid=3fa6d147bf94bec5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('SuperButton').onclick = function()
    {
        if(document.body.className != 'new_class')
        {
            document.body.className = 'new_class';
        }
        else
        {
            document.body.className = '';
        }
    }
}
</script>
<style>
body { background: #23ff0c; min-height: 100%; }
.new_class { background: #FF0; }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<button id="SuperButton" name="SuperButton">Super Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: для полной смены стиля страницы такой метод будет слишком многословным...

Comment: ТС'а по сути больше волшебная кнопка интересовала) Понятно что с точки зрения глобальной смены стиля подход нужен другой.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно это реализовывают через специальный класс, например у тега боди

```
body.style1 {background:#fff}
body.style1 a{color:#cc0000;}

body.style2 {background:#000}
body.style2 a{color:#ccc;}
```

и по клику на кнопку манипулируют этим классом, а все стили в одном файле

Comment: интересно, допустим у меня есть 2 класса для body (body1, body2), а вот кнопку как такую написать я не представляю 8-(

Comment: $('changeStyleButton').click(function(){
   $('body').addClass('style2');
});

Answer (score 2):

Вот смена стилей как работает в продакшине [JQuery UI Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) (закладка Themes).

Вот функция, которая это делает:

```
//function to append a new theme stylesheet with the new style changes
function updateCSS(locStr){
    $("link[href*=parseTheme\\.css\\.php]:last").after('<link href="/themeroller/css/parseTheme.css.php?'+ encodeURIComponent( locStr ) +'" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />');
    if($("link[href*=parseTheme\\.css\\.php]").size() > 3){
        $("link[href*=parseTheme\\.css\\.php]:first").remove();
    }
};
```

Т.е. это фактически ответ [@inferus-vv](/users/6278/inferus-vv), только здесь jquery использован, здесь он просто для удобства...

Работает в опере, хроме, сафари, лисе, и даже в ie. еще на андроиде в стоковом браузере тоже работает.

Answer (score 1):

- Добавьте аттрибут `id` элементу `link` который `rel="stylesheet"`
- В скрипте находите этот элемент и меняйте ему аттрибут `href`

Страница перезагружаться естественно не будет, но таблица стилей загрузится.

А вообще это убого при наличии поддержки rel="alternate stylesheet".

Comment: моих знаний JS хватило только на

    <html>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function color(c) {document.body.style.backgroundColor=c}
    </script>
    <input type='button' value='красный фон' onclick='color("red")'>
    <input type='button' value='черный фон' onclick='color("black")'>
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: @mixalef, нет-нет, я предлагал сменить URL "главной" таблицы стилей.