# Как сделать на сайте изменения цвета фона и текста пользователем?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii2, background-color

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы пользователь сам мог выбрать цвет фона и цвет текста сам(через какой либо виджет типа color picker или чтобы я смог предложить несколько вариантов для выбора) и чтобы выбранный цвет сохранялся в бд. Хочу сделать так: при выборе или при наведении сразу же менять цвет, для того, чтобы пользователь мог видеть как будет смотреться цвет. Проект написан на Yii2. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Используйте css переменные, и манипулируйте ими

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/98931/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: В чем вопрос? в реализации или как построить логику? Берете идентификатор пользователя, кука или ид(если авторизирован), даете выбор цвета, выбранный цвет храните в бд с привязкой к пользователю (не авторизированных нужно чистить через время). Ну и выводите сохраненный цвет...

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое, попробую